# Why do we need curies in Spring HATEOAS

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

I have basic understanding of what Spring's HATEOAS is, and also those basic HETEOAS links, like:

```
 _links : {
     self: { href: "http://myhost/person/1" }
}
```

I tried to search online but i can't really get a grasp of what curies is in HATEOAS. I can't understand the need of its existence. Why is it needed?

```
  curies: {
     name: "ex",
     href: "http://example.com/rels/{rel}",
     templated: true
},
```

Answer (score 1):

CURIEs provide a shortcut or template for linking to API documentation within a HAL based API response.

Read more at https://www.mikestowe.com/blog/2015/01/what-the-heck-are-curies.php